# Why do I get access denied when I open a signed URL from Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I need to open a signed URL from Amazon S3 and I keep getting access denied.

For example, accessing this URL:

```
https://aidin.s3.amazonaws.com/aidin/staging/attachments/faxattach/94DD749z65ejkh353?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJPBOMKHDQ5WNJM3Q&Expires=1373047778&Signature=Y%2F968F9LIfkfHwsp7T8P0CqjQhQ%3D
```

From this code:

```
 def download path
    local_file = File.new 'attachment' + (Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+(rand * 1000000).round.to_s) + ".pdf", 'wb+'
    # HTTPError is caught in the /process in faxattach.rb
    uri = URI.parse(path)
    http_object = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http_object.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    http_object.start do |http|
      response = http.request request
      local_file.write(response.read_body)
    end
    debugger
    local_file.rewind
    local_file
  end
```

I'm getting this in `local_file`:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>11A4FB2DF920A272</RequestId><HostId>6qH/f602NxfJa38oW+67Q+5GVx5XD+BJqTzNVR5IhhnvEDhiXUoTR0K90/quZTWk</HostId></Error>
```

Does anyone know why? The URL opens fine in my browser, and I need the extra query parameters like `AWSAccessKeyID`, `Expires` etc., which are there for security reasons.

Comment: Could you be getting a redirect that you're not handling? What does `response` contain?

Comment: @theTinMan Response is a 403 forbidden (#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>), and I assume that's what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify and use OpenURI:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://aidin.s3.amazonaws.com/aidin/staging/attachments/faxattach/94DD749z65ejkh353?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJPBOMKHDQ5WNJM3Q&Expires=1373047778&Signature=Y%2F968F9LIfkfHwsp7T8P0CqjQhQ%3D"

File.open( 'attachment' + (Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+(rand * 1000000).round.to_s) + ".pdf", 'wb+') do |file|
  file << open(url).read
end
```

Comment: `open(url).read` is going to pull the entire resource into memory, then pass it to the file handle. If the file is larger than memory you'll have just DOS'd yourself. Instead, pass a block to `open`. See the first two examples in the [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) doc.

Comment: Yes. this is recommended in the conditions you mention.

Comment: This is super weird. So that code works perfectly, if I'm running it outside of a Sinatra app. However, I need it in a Sinatra app, and with Sinatra, it gives me a 403. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1045696 that seems really unlikely... put into a github repo and let me see the code?

Comment: @user1045696 it works fine if: you have the path in a local variable, it worked fine. using the debugger, you can see that it chops off the URL string. So, you need to CGI::encode the url that you use in the URL. then, you need to CGI::unencode before you use the path. This part really is a different question though.

Answer (score 0):

You want `request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path)`

My test in context:

```
require 'net/http'
path = "https://aidin.s3.amazonaws.com/aidin/staging/attachments/faxattach/94DD749z65ejkh353?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJPBOMKHDQ5WNJM3Q&Expires=1373047778&Signature=Y%2F968F9LIfkfHwsp7T8P0CqjQhQ%3D"
uri = URI.parse(path)
http_object = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http_object.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path)
http_object.start do |http|
  response = http.request request
  puts response.read_body
end
```

Comment: What if the file requested is larger than available memory?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm suggesting you change the syntax of that one line. Worked for me.

Comment: @aceofspades I'm getting a 403